# Accessing users Download folder in python

Tags: python, django

I have lunched a simple video downloader app in django with apache2 server.I tried access users local download directory with `Path = os.path.expanduser("~") + "/Downloads/"`.But whenever someone tries to download video its downloading inside servers folder i.e `/home/SERVER USER NAME/Download` but not users download directory.How could i make it download inside users local Download directory?

**views.py**

```
def download(request):
    MusicPath = os.path.expanduser("~") + "/Downloads/"
    if request.method == 'GET':

        context = {
            'videos_1080': PY.streams.get_by_itag('137'),
            'videos_720': PY.streams.get_by_itag('22'),
            'videos_normal': PY.streams.filter(progressive=True, subtype='mp4').first()
        }
        return render(request, "youtube/download.html",context)

    if request.method == 'POST':
            videos = PY.streams.filter(progressive=True, subtype='mp4').first()
            videos.download(MusicPath)
            messages.success(request, 'Video has been successfully downloaded !')
            return redirect('home')
        return render(request, "youtube/download.html", {"title": PY.title, "id": PY.video_id, 'views': PY.views})
```

This code is just a sample giving basic implementation

Comment: @PedroLobito please review it

Comment: Your code doesn't match your question. `Path = os.path.expanduser("~") + "/Downloads/"`, is nowhere to be seen.

Comment: just a typing mistake.Try to understand

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your problem correctly, I guess `os.path.expanduser("~")` will give you the path to a user used by the WebServer. For example, if you use Apache2, the default user would be www-data, so `os.path.expanduser("~")` would return `/home/www-data/Downloads`. (Which does not exists by default).

In case, you want to use the current user's folder, I would recommend collecting the username of the current person. `path = "home/{}/Downloads".format(username)`. Even better, if you use a database, or a file, place all of the downloaded content in a single folder, and you keep tracking the owner of the video, due to non existent users, folders.

In case it is a cloud based app, I would recommend

- Create a login page
- Download the videos into a single folder
- Keep tracking the owner of the file in a database, or a textfile

**EDIT**

In case it is not a cloud based app, and it should download a video into your download folder, just hardcode your path into the source. (Don't forget permissions)

Then hardcode your Downloads path into the source.

Change

```
MusicPath = os.path.expanduser("~") + "/Downloads/"
```

To

```
MusicPath = "/home/{}/Downloads/".format(username)
```

Where `username` is your username.

You can not use `os.path.expanduser("~")` nor `os.getenv('username')` because the user who starts the process is used by the webserver and there is no way the program could find out who you really are. It will always return data about the user used by the webserver.

Comment: its not a cloud based app.Iam new to programming and managed to build a simple video downloader using pytube.It was working fine on local host but on production its not downloading ion desired location..Its just simple app so i dont want to create user database and user login page.Copy paste youtube url click download button and it should download the videos..Can i use os.getenv('username') ?

Comment: 'username' not defined

Comment: Well, define username. Add username = “your username here”.

Comment: what if i browsed it from another pc?or if someone else tried to download from another pc

Comment: Then, you need a specific username, otherwise you will not be able to identify the user. Check 'cloud based app' for further information.

Comment: what if i host on a pythonanywhere?

Comment: Does not matter until you have permissions

Comment: You can put the path into the url, but you need that data from somewhere. Its not about passing the data, the problem is about how do you know whos using the computer now

Comment: https://github.com/AndreMiras/tubedl/blob/214f954bb14a1e611cc3626500fbe64f9c0f3545/videodl/views.py#L164                  Any idea about this?